# Error message "Symbol's function definition is void: org-link-types" when I open a .org file

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

I tried to get the "capture"-Feature to work.

I did the following things:

- Installation of the newest Version of the Org mode
  (now the version 8.2.10)
- To get the capture feature work [i added to my .emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622603/org-mode-setup-problem-when-trying-to-use-capture):

```el
;;https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622603/org-mode-setup-problem-when-trying-to-use-capture

;(add-to-list 'load-path "/nils/home/emacs.d/org-7.01h/lisp")

(require 'org-install)

(require 'org) ;; maybe this line is redundant

;; Verzeichnis für "org-capture" festlegen
 (setq org-default-notes-file (concat org-directory "/notes.org"))

(define-key global-map "\C-cc" 'org-capture)
```

After these changes i get the error message
`Symbol's function definition is void: org-link-types`
when I open a .org file.

I don't know how to handle this error message.

Comment: You get this error because `org-link-types` is a variable in orgmode 8.2.10 and not a function. But, from [this search](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22defun+org-link-types%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=m1FaWJivL6vP8AfV2b7YBA) it looks like this symbol has a function definition in newer versions of orgmode (version 9.x). Maybe, you mixed different versions of orgmode?

Comment: Yes, this is possible.

Comment: Directly after the installation emacs told me, that the version of org-mode ist 9.0.2, now it tells me it's the version 8.2.10.

Comment: So you should get rid of one of these versions. It may be that one of these versions comes from the package manager of yor system (e.g. `apt-get` under linux) and the other one from elpa or melpa (these are found unter `~/.emacs.d/elpa/org-20161017/`).

Comment: Are you using Spacemacs ? In version 0.200.7 "org layer" seems to be causing such version conflicts in org-mode. I found a related issue [here](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/8074) , and proposed a solution with a patch (also in [PR #8399](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/pull/8399)).

Comment: @RockyRoad I use spacemacs with the org layer, and have this annoying error which I have no emacs-skills to track down, thank you for spotting its origin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problems with uninstall all org-packages in elpa.
Now the my .org files open without the error and the links work fine.

Thanks to Tobias for his hints!